# Disable Minimize Button, but Keep Cross and Maximize Buttons - WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to know how to disable the Minimize button, but keep the Maximize/Restore button and the Close button (the red "X").

Here's an image of what I want my window's buttons on the top-right to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You may need to use PInvoke here. Basically you're importing SetWindowLong and GetWindowLong functions and setting corresponding flags to Win API window using it's handle(hwnd)

```
private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
private const int WS_MINIMIZE = -131073;
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

private static void CanMinimize(Window w)
{
  var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(w).Handle;
  long value = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
  SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (int)(value & ~WS_MINIMIZE));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blablablaster is basically right -- you need to P/Invoke a couple of Windows API calls -- but the following TechNet article also describes when/where you should make the call to the Windows API:

[WPF: Disabling or Hiding the Minimize, Maximize or Close Button Of a Window](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29183.wpf-disabling-or-hiding-the-minimize-maximize-or-close-button-of-a-window.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think WPF provides a way to disable just the minimize button. What you can do is disable the complete title bar and create a custom title bar for yourself. Check [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/121576-c#-wpf-custom-title-bar-tutorial/#-wpf-custom-title-bar-tutorial/) out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it

```
Private Sub WindowAddChange_StateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.StateChanged

    If sender.windowstate = WindowState.Minimized Then
        Me.WindowState = WindowState.Normal
    End If

End Sub
```