# WPF window should not be moved,resized and should only contain minimize,close buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml, maximize-window

I'm trying to set up a WPF window.

- Window should be in maximized state always
- Window cannot be moved or resized
- It should contain minimize and close button but not maximize button

I tried the following XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="BasicImagingStandAlone"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myUserControl="clr-namespace:WpfUserControlLibrary;assembly=WpfUserControlLibrary"
    Title="BasicImagingStandAlone" Icon="desktopicon.png" MinWidth="600" MinHeight="350" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    Height="600" Width="1200" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None"  ResizeMode="NoResize">
</Window>
```

The output of the xaml is a window in maximized state which cannot be moved or resized but with no buttons.
  How can i achieve all the requirments at once?

Answer (score 6):

This question is almost 2 years old, but just in case someone has the same requirements.

In WPF you can use the helper class `HwndSource` to hook into the window procedure which then can be used to process window messages.

So in XAML set `WindowState="Maximized"`, `ResizeMode="CanMinimize"`, and override the `SourceInitialized` :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" SourceInitialized="MainWindow_SourceInitialized">
```

And the code-behind (a modification from [an answer in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2400888/983646)):

```cs
private void MainWindow_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(helper.Handle);
    source.AddHook(WndProc);
}

const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;
const int SC_RESTORE = 0xF120;

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            int command = wParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
            if (command == SC_MOVE)
            {
                // prevent user from moving the window
                handled = true;
            }
            else if (command == SC_RESTORE && WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                // prevent user from restoring the window while it is maximized
                // (but allow restoring when it is minimized)
                handled = true;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Don't forget to include: `using System.Windows.Interop;`

This should meet OP's 3 requirements:

- Window in maximized state
- Window cannot be moved or
  resized (including by dragging or double-clicking the title bar)
- Window's minimize and close buttons are enabled, but restore/maximize button is disabled

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find XAML only way. But this code will help you

To show close and minimize buttons

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowState="Maximized"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="425">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And if you double click on the window title bar, it will resize to normal, to avoid this use following code.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
}

private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Normal)
    {
        WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry,this won't work.All the 3 requirements should be satisfied at once.

Comment: All the requirements are meeting right? Which requirement is not meeting

Comment: With the given code, window can be moved by dragging and it gets restored automatically

Answer (score 0):

In order to touch the titlebar of the window you will have to import user32 APIs as described in this answer:

[Disable Minimize Button, but Keep Cross and Maximize Buttons - WPF, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381933/disable-minimize-button-but-keep-cross-and-maximize-buttons-wpf-c-sharp)

Also you can set the ResizeMode to CanMinimize. This will disable the maximize button. But in order to hide it you will have to use user32 apis as described above